# Why does `multiprocessing.Process()` create an intermediate process on windows?

Tags: python, windows

I am exploring parent-child process relationships on Windows 10 and I have written a script in python 3.7.2 to spawn a tree of child processes. I am using `multiprocessing.Process()` to spawn the child processes. Each `process` logs its `process.id`, the `process.id` of its parent, and the `process.id` of the children it creates.

On my local laptop running MacOS this behaves as expected; process `1` creates processes `2` and `3`, and `2` and `3` each report that their parent is `1`. However, on windows process `1` creates two processes, say `A` and `B`, and processes `2` and `3` report that `A` and `B` are their parents, respectively. Why are these intermediate processes created? Why not just spawn `2` and `3` directly?

Here is the script and the output of the first few log files for each system:

```py
import sys
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

tree = {
    1 : [2, 3],
    2 : [4, 5, 6],
    3 : [7, 8],
    7 : [9, 10]
}

def start_child(my_id):
    children_ids = tree.get(my_id, None)

    child_processes = []
    if children_ids:
        for child_id in children_ids:
            child = Process(target=start_child, args=(child_id,))
            child_processes.append(child)
            child.start()

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    with open(f'{current_dir}/{my_id}.log', 'w') as out:
        out.write(f"I am {os.getpid()}.\nMy parent process is {os.getppid()}.\n")
        for child in child_processes:
            out.write(f"I spawned process {child.pid}, named {child.name}.\n")

    time.sleep(50)
    for child in child_processes:
        child.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_child(1)
```

First three logs from MacOS (expected behavior):

```
# 1.log
I am 40847.
My parent process is 40552.
I spawned process 40857.
I spawned process 40858.
```

```
# 2.log
I am 40857.
My parent process is 40847.
I spawned process 40859.
I spawned process 40860.
I spawned process 40862.
```

```
# 3.log
I am 40858.
My parent process is 40847.
I spawned process 40861.
I spawned process 40863.
```

First three logs from Windows 10 (unexpected behavior):

```
# 1.log
I am 6908.
My parent process is 1392.
I spawned process 7608.
I spawned process 5212.
```

```
# 2.log
I am 6512.
My parent process is 7608.
I spawned process 10780.
I spawned process 5520.
I spawned process 1176.
```

```
# 3.log
I am 2032.
My parent process is 5212.
I spawned process 3424.
I spawned process 7776.
```

As you can see on Windows the parent `process.id` for processes `2` and `3` are the children of process `1`, rather than process `1` itself.

I'm sure I could dig into the `multiprocessing` implementation for windows, but I'm hoping someone else already has...

Comment: I assume you're using a virtual environment. The new venv launcher executable gets set as `sys.executable`, which is useful in general but a problem for multiprocessing. This issue has been resolved in 3.7.3 with the addition of a new `sys._base_executable` attribute that's used internally by multiprocessing.

Comment: @eryksun That is correct, I am using a virtual environment. And it looks like upgrading to 3.7.3 fixes multiprocessing. Thanks for the tip!